# JSTree context menu popping up behind tree and page content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

I'm implementing JSTree in an Asp.net MVC3 application. The problem I'm having is the popup context menu pops up hidden behind the tree. Not sure what is going on here. Is there a particular order of things to ensure that the popup appears in front (on top)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a z-index issue. Solution can be found at this link: [Google JSTree forum post: jstree and blockui don't work well together](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jstree/context%2420menu%2420behind/jstree/OnIIpPLx2us/fObPi6e2zO8J)

Thank you Ivan.